# Creating DataBricks Azure Key Vault Secret Scope Backend using Rest Api and DataBricks CLI

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create the secrete scope which is backend by azure key vault so when I tried with secret api, I got an error has

Input:

```
response = requests.post(
    'https://%s/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create' % (DOMAIN),
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN,},
    json={"scope": "my-simple-azure-keyvault-scope",
    "scope_backend_type": "AZURE_KEYVAULT",
  "backend_azure_keyvault":
  {
    "resource_id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/azure-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/my-azure-kv",
    "dns_name": "https://my-azure-kv.vault.azure.net/"
  },
  "initial_manage_principal": "users"
})
```

Output:

```
{
  "error_code": "INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE",
  "message": "Scope with Azure KeyVault must have userAADToken defined!"
}
```

I tried with Different method which is Databricks Cli for that I faced a error, So I created a Secret scope using databricks  UI and tried to access through cli

Input:

```
databricks configure --token
Databricks Host (should begin with https://): https://adb-...azuredatabricks.net/
Token: 

D:\Users\>databricks secrets list-scopes
```

Output:

```
Error: b'Bad Request'
```

In Cmd prompt

Is there a way to get AAD token, I have implemented [Microsoft documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token) for getting token but didn't work

Comment: please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-databricks-cli

Comment: Can you please update the question with more details? How are you calling or getting the error in option 1 and what is the command you are using in option 2?

Comment: @Venkatesan I have tried that method only then I got the error that to use AAD token

Comment: @SimpalKumar I have edited the question and provide the sample code which I tried

Comment: How are you generating the bearer token?

Comment: @SimpalKumar Bearer Token generate by multiple way using api and cli but for now taking manually from databricks UI user settings

Answer (score -1):

Update May 2023: now it’s possible to use service principal to create a secret scope from azure keyvault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/product/2023/april#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-with-a-service-principal

This is well known limit described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-databricks-cli) linked in the comment - you must use user's AAD token to create a secret scope baked by the Azure KeyVault.

The simplest way to create a secret scope is not to use API, but instead use the Databricks CLI - there is a command to create a secret scope:

```bash
databricks secrets create-scope --scope <scope-name> \  
  --scope-backend-type AZURE_KEYVAULT --resource-id <azure-keyvault-resource-id> \
  --dns-name <azure-keyvault-dns-name>
```

You also don't even need to configure CLI - specify `DATABRICKS_HOST` and `DATABRICKS_TOKEN` environment variables, like this:

```bash
export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token -o tsv --query accessToken --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d)
export DATABRICKS_HOST=https://adb-.....azuredatabricks.net
```

Note that here we're getting user's AAD token by using `az account get-access-token` command from Azure CLI (make sure you did `az login` before)